# Case when homomorphism is onto based on its behaviour between subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

One of the thing about rereading theorems is that you something get a fresh insight that wasn't obvious before.

> A property of homomorphism acting on subgroups:
>   Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from a group G to a group $\bar{G}$ and let H be a subgroup of G.
>
> If $\bar{H}$ is a subgroup of $\bar{G}$, then, $\phi^{-1}\left ( \bar{H} \right )=\left \{ x \in G:\phi\left ( x \right ) \in \bar{H} \right \}$ is a subgroup of G

The above property seem to suggest that not only is the homomorphism injective by definition, it also adds on the property of it being surjective.
This is a trivial question but I would like to know if I am correct.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Define the homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ by $f(g): = e$, where $e$ is the identity.  This is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: What exactly makes you say this makes a homomorphism look injective and surjective? (Try considering what this says about the trivial homomorphism $\phi$ taking every element to the identity - maybe this will clarify your question.)

Comment: A homomorphism from a group $G$ to a group $H$ is not necessarily injective, and regardless of whether or not it's injective, it's also not necessarily surjective.

Comment: @quasi I understand it is not necessarily surjective. But with the above property, would we be justified in making the claim that the homormophism is at least surjective? After all, from that property, every element in the codomain is mapped from an element in the domain

Comment: @quasi I now took notice of that counterexample provided by Joe.

Comment: @Mathematicing: No, it's not correct. You've already been given a counterexample. As regards "the above property", the fact that the inverse image of a subgroup $K$ of $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ does not imply that every element of $K$ is in the forward image. All that's implied is if $f$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, and if $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $f(f^{-1}(K)) \subseteq K$, possiby a _proper_ subset.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $f : X \to Y$ and a subset $S \subseteq Y$ the notation $f^{-1}(S)$ is defined by

$$ f^{-1}(S) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in S \}$$

It has nothing to do with whether or not $f$ is injective or surjective.

For example, take the map $\mathbf{Z}/4 \to \mathbf{Z}/2 \times \mathbf{Z}/2$ given by $f(a) = (a,0)$. I.e. $$f(0) = (0,0),\; f(1) = (1,0),\; f(2) = (0,0),\; f(3) = (1,0).$$

Then

- $f^{-1}(\{(0,0)\}) = \{0, 2\}$
- $f^{-1}(\mathbf{Z}/2 \times \{0\}) = \{0,1,2,3\}$
- $f^{-1}(\{0\} \times \mathbf{Z}/2) = \{0, 2\}$
- $f^{-1}(\mathbf{Z}/2 \times \mathbf{Z}/2) = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$

Answer (score 0):

The homomorphism is not injective by definition, a definition of a group

homomorphism from (G, ∗) to (G', ·) is a function h : G → G' 
such that for all x and y in G it holds that
h(u*v)=h(u).h(v).

we called a homomorphism which is injective a Monomorphism,
and a homomorphism which is surjective an Epimorphism,
and a homomorphism which is bijective an Isomorphism.

Comment: While mono/epi morphisms is technically correct, in my experience it is more common to just say they are injective or surjective when working in groups. It is also worth pointing out that it is a theorem that they are the same(surjective and epi is not completely trivial). This post also doesn't really answer anything, you just make a statement and say some definitions.

Comment: i just tried to illustrate the hom. dose not means injective and there is a name to injective hom.

Comment: The name for injective homomorphisms is injective homomorphism, monoic and epic happen to coincide in the category of groups (they are not the same in all categories though, for example in Rings epic is not the same as surj, and it isn't exactly easy to see they epic coincides with surj in group) so sure you could call the them monic or epic, but the question wasn't concerned about terminology.

Comment: Theoretically every homomorphism is injective or every one is surjective, which is not addressed by your answer. In fact you actually accidentally illustrate something else in your comments: epimorphism does not mean surjective, it isn't part of the definition, but they happen to be the same in the category of groups. Maybe it happens that homomorphism are the same as injections or surjections or monics or epics etc in Grp.  The OP brought up a specific observation, that they thought might imply that homomorphisms are injective and surjective -- you don't address that in your answer.